# ESLint throwing error in html and template files

Tags: javascript, angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have an angular app and have just configured ESLint on the project and am getting this error on my index.html and it is complaining about a closing tag and not correctly reading this, I would like to ignore errors like this in the .html files. I am getting this error
on the below tag

error  Parsing error: '>' expected

**index.html**

<!doctype html>

Here is my esLinerc.json file

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jasmine": true
},
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:jasmine/recommended"
],
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "jasmine"
],
"ignorePatterns": [
    "/**/*.js",
    "**/vendor/*.js",
    "/**/*.component.html"
],
"rules": {
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": "off",
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "off",
    "no-irregular-whitespace": "off",
   
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["*.component.html"],
        "parser": "@angular-eslint/template-parser",
        "parserOptions": {
          "project": "./tsconfig.app.json",
          "ecmaVersion": 2020,
          "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "rules": {
            "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-implied-eval": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": "off",
            "strict": "off",
            "import/first": "off",
            "lines-around-directive": "off"
          },
        "plugins": ["@angular-eslint/template"]
      }
]
```

}

I had installed

"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.27.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.27.1",

earlier and read that i might have to install @angular-eslint/template-parser and have installed this as well ,

"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.5.0",
hoping that would ignore the bogus error and other errors where eslint is expecting a closing tag for component directives.

I have tried to add the **.html files as well to the ignore patterns but am still getting template errors that are not valid. Can someone please point out what exact i need to make to ignore errors on .html files

Comment: Did you make a mistake when you added `html`-files to `ignorePatterns`? It should work: `"/**/*.html"`

Comment: Hi @Eugene yes I ended up trying this and this worked, i thought i had to include  "/**/*.component.html" but "/**/*.html" in ignorePatterns and it worked, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore non-component `html` files. Just edit `ignorePatterns` section:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
  "/**/*.html",
],
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

right before your html docutype

Comment: this doesnt work, i tried it both by adding // eslint-disable-next-line. and as a html comment like <!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->, I still get the error

Comment: are you sure your ESlint is configured correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Try to update from Android Studio if you have it, in the top menu click "Tools" > "Flutter" > "Flutter Upgrade".

Otherwise run "Flutter Upgrade -f"[image]